# How Can I Cancel The OAuth Consent Verification Process?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-openid, developer-console

I was testing functionality on a website that I'm developing that allows the user to sign in using their Google account.  I filled in the "OAuth consent screen" in the Google Developer's Console, including all of the URLs to allow Google to redirect a user back to my website with the necessary OpenID information.  Everything works, but I used test URLs on the "OAuth consent screen".  Afterwards, I made the very costly mistake of clicking the button at the bottom of the screen labeled `Submit for verification`.  I should have clicked the button labeled `Save`.  The URLs on my OAuth consent screen all have internal hostnames, so they're not accessible from the Internet.  Is there any way that I can cancel the request to Google for verification?  The page is currently frozen, and it won't let me change any of the URLs until I inevitably fail the verification process.  There is also a message that states that verification may take up to 4-6 weeks, which is a long time to wait for something with a known outcome...

I know this may not be the right forum for this question.  However, [Google's own support page](https://console.developers.google.com/support/overview) links to StackOverflow, and I'm sure web developers must encounter this problem quite frequently.  I tried looking on Google's FAQ pages, but didn't see anything about canceling the verification process.  It's quite possible that I missed something....

**Edit**  I've received an e-mail from the Google Cloud Platform notifying me that my request to have my app verified has been denied.  This makes sense, since I completed the Consent form with incorrect test URLs.  However, the `Save` button on the OAuth consent screen is still disabled.  The screen appears to be in the verification process.  Perhaps this is the intended workflow for the screen.  At any rate, the original request for verification was denied within a day or two, which was quite fast considering the 4-6 weeks that Google allows for the process.  If anyone can confirm or deny that this is the intended behavior of the OAuth consent screen, I would be happy to mark their answer as correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had this issue and I managed to cancel the verification process.

Simply click "BACK TO TESTING" in "Publishing status" and click "PUBLISH APP", this changed my Verification Status to "Verification not required".

Remember to remove any scopes or logo that requires verification before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I'm inclined to believe that this is the intended behavior of the OAuth consent screen.  3 days after the verification request has been declined, the message `Your consent screen is being verified. This may take up to several weeks. Your last approved consent screen is still in use.` is still being displayed.  I now believe that further changes to the screen, such as updating the URLs, will require the verification process to be restarted, since the `Save` button remains disabled.

Comment: Any update on this? Can you edit your OAuth consent screen now? Is you can, how long does it take before you can edit?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  You've probably already gotten the answer, but in my case, they eventually responded.  Basically, my answer ended up being correct at the time it was written.  The screen could not be updated without retrying the entire process.  I guess this is/was by design, but I was confused by the message "Your consent screen is being verified...", since I could not make any changes in the meantime.  There really wasn't anything that I could do other than wait for their reply by e-mail.