# How to revert to previously verified Google OAuth consent screen state?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

We have been using Google APIs and had a verified Google OAuth consent screen. Recently, we added a few sensitive scopes for a different application in our system. We used the same OAuth screen/Google project and restarted the verification process.
This process is taking time and we are now thinking of creating another Google project to keep the new scopes/application separate from existing OAuth screen, similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70757207/should-separate-projects-be-used-for-different-oauth-use-cases).

How can we cancel the verification process and go back to previous state? There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285300/how-can-i-cancel-the-oauth-consent-verification-process) but it does not solve the problem for a previously verified application.

We have replied to google email and tried reaching out to their support team but no response have been received till now.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76000361/8016720) work in your case? If not, edit your post with details. Any change you make to the OAuth Client requires verification. Sometimes that is automatic but depends on which scopes your client requests.

Comment: The difference is that our application is already live(being used for other scopes) and verified once whereas in the said answer, it talks about first time verification.

Comment: AFAIK, the previous state no longer matters. If you change something, your client is re-verified. Sometimes automatically.